# Scope and Linked Lists in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, scope

I'm trying to get more comfortable building and using linked lists in C, and for the most part I think I have the basics down. However, I am running into problems in regards to Scope, specifically the linkage of a Pointer to a Pointer of structs.

In my linked_list.c implementation I am using a `main` function to test out and play around with the linked list functions I've built. But the eventual goal is to run Main from another file, and only reference the few functions I'd need externally from a header file.

The implementation I'm using right now DOES work, but it seems to rely on me declaring the `struct list**` inside my (temporary)) `main` function.

It's my understanding that if you declare a variable/pointer outside of a block, you can control the linkage to be internal, accessible to other functions in the file,  using the `static` command. What I would like to be able to do is call a function like `void initialize_list()` from OUTSIDE the program and have it initialize this internally `linked list**`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
   int value;
   struct node *next;
};

struct list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    int size; //  Maintains current size of list
};

static struct list** work_list;

void dirty_init(void){
    struct list* new_list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    new_list->head = NULL;
    new_list->tail = NULL;
    new_list->size = 0;
    *work_list = new_list;
}
```

Running my `dirty_init` function returns a segfault.

The version of code that DOES work is quite similar, but it seems to rely on the `**work_list` being declared inside of my `main` function before passing it to `initialize_list`.

```
void initialize_list(struct list **out_list){
    struct list* my_list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    my_list->head = NULL;
    my_list->tail = NULL;
    my_list->size = 0;
    *out_list = my_list;
}
int main(void){
    int i;
    struct list   **work_list;
    initialize_list(work_list);
}
```

This is all well and good, but it has the drawback of making my `**work_list` pointer internally linked to the Main block. Any ideas where I am going wrong trying to get the `dirty_init` function to work?

Answer (score 2):

This here:

```
int main(void){
    int i;
    struct list   **work_list;
    initialize_list(work_list);
}
```

can't work. C is pass by value and you pass an uninitialized value, which is then used as a result pointer. Did you mean

```
int main(void){
    int i;
    struct list   *work_list;
    initialize_list(&work_list);
}
```

instead?

Comment: Ah, but it does work! I have a bunch of functions for adding nodes and popping from the list that I run after the initialize_list() function and they all seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to word my question is, how come the dirty_init function segfaults and the initialize_list() version does what I think it should?

Comment: @user3407513 No it doesn't work. It just doesn't crash immediately. To see this, initialize `struct list **worklist = NULL` and watch `*out_list = my_list` dereference a NULL pointer. Your code scribbles on random memory.

Comment: @user3407513, you can think about it from a general rule standpoint. Any time you are passing a **pointer as an argument**, and then changing what that pointer points to, you must pass the **address** of the pointer to the function, otherwise in the function you will be operating on a **copy** of that pointer (with a different address) and the changes will not be seen in the calling function (`main` in your case). In a linked list, this generally applies to the list initialization, (and changing/deleting the first or last node in a circular list)

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys,  but it unfortunately they haven't solved my problems with scope. I don't want to pass the pointer as an argument. I want to run dirty_init() and initialize an internally linked static struct list pointer OUTSIDE any function blocks. I'm probably dense, but I can't seem to make it work.